# Why generating object files

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, gnu-make

I am currently learning, how to use `make` and `Makefile`s in depth. During that process, one question came up: I have the impression, that a lot of `Makefile`s first generating object files, and then link them into a library or another executable file.

So my question is: Is this best practice? And if yes, why?

Comment: what is the point of using a makefile then if you build everything every time.  the point is to build what changed and leave what didnt alone.  thus objects or libraries.  Use a build script if you dont want to use makefiles.

Comment: Imagine you change a single variable name. Should this force the compiler to compile *all* code again?

Answer (score 1):

Generating object files separately from the corresponding source files makes sense in `Makefile`s because this way there's no need to remake objects files from untouched source files.